# Rtrieve files from FTP Server

Tags: ftp, mainframe, ftp-client

We have a Mainframe Batch job which runs every 15 mins and looks for a file on FTP server. If File is found job executes and retrieves the file. If file is not found then job gets cancelled. 90% of the time, job does not find any file on FTP server and gets cancelled.

Is there any way to avoid running job every 15 mins to check file on FTP server? Please provide suggestions. Non-Mainframe option is also open.

Thanks,
Rahul

Comment: I think the question is too broad. You essentially need some way to know before running the job if a the remote file exists or not. You could do this by querying the FTP server, but this is what the existing job already does. If there are any other ways to get these information depends on your specific but unknown situation, i.e. maybe whoever puts the file there can also notify someone some way that the file can now be retrieved.

Comment: Thank you Steffen. Yes. I am looking for task which can run at FTP server side and FTP the file to Mainframe. It can be any other technology which can do this in an efficient way. On Mainframe side, job can be triggered as soon as file is received.

Comment: @RahulKulkarni Then you do not have a programming question. Please move it to [su] or [sf]. And even there, your question might still be considered too broad.

Comment: There is a large amount of technologies available for this like sending a mail and automatically processing it on the other side, having a simple HTTP or TCP server ... . To get these things working and stable will take some time depending on your experience and there is no solution you just have to take, i.e. you need to adapt these on your specific use case. It is likely that the current solution of polling the FTP server is the best compromise between usability and costs - you just have to accept that it will throw errors if the file does not exist and just consider this a normal behavior.

Comment: Can you tell us more about your environment and what scheduling technologies are in place ?  For instance, IBM Workload Scheduling, CA CA-7/11 or BMC Ctrl-M or other?  Concur on moving this to Superuser.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like an ideal situation for WebSphere MQ. Message queues ensure the data file is processed once and only once after it has been received. It has a richer security and much better performance than a solution involving FTP and programs cobbled around it. When the message is received (i.e. the file that you were trying to send), MQ can trigger a batch job to process the file.

Here's a COBOL example of how to get a message off the queue:
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.ref.dev.doc/q089830_.htm

Here's a good article on configuring MQ to trigger the batch job:
http://thebigoldmainframe.blogspot.com/2012/09/mq-batch-triggering-process.html